# How to add Varchar checkbox values in MySql?

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I'm trying to add Varchar values from checkbox to mysql and it adding string "1" in the checked checkboxes. How I can make it to add Varchar values like below?

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['dr_add'])) {
  $lightv = isset($_POST['l_vehicle']);
  $van = isset($_POST['van']);
  $truck = isset($_POST['truck']);
  $trailer = isset($_POST['tr_trailer']);
  mysql_query("INSERT INTO driving(user_id, country,l_vehicle,van, truck , tr_trailer) VALUES('$user->employeeid','$lightv','$van','$truck','$trailer')") or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
<input type="checkbox" name="l_vehicle" value="Light Vehicle"/>Light Vehicle
<input type="checkbox" name="van" value="Van">Van
<input type="checkbox" name="truck" value="Truck"/>Truck
<input type="checkbox" name="tr_trailer" value="Truck&Trailer"/>Truck&Trailer
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using  `$trailer = isset($_POST['tr_trailer']);` and it is wrong :

User below code :

```
 $trailer = isset($_POST['tr_trailer'])?$_POST['tr_trailer']:"";
```

Use this for all checkboxes

Comment: Correct. It will return `0` or `1`.

Comment: Thank you very much, exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

> [isset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) — Determine if a variable is set and is not NULL

**UPDATED CODE**

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['dr_add'])) {
  $lightv = isset($_POST['l_vehicle']) ? $_POST['l_vehicle'] : "";
  $van = isset($_POST['van']) ? $_POST['van'] : "";
  $truck = isset($_POST['truck']) ? $_POST['truck'] : "";
  $trailer = isset($_POST['tr_trailer']) ? $_POST['tr_trailer'] : "";

  mysql_query("INSERT INTO driving(user_id, country,l_vehicle,van, truck , tr_trailer) VALUES('$user->employeeid','$lightv','$van','$truck','$trailer')") or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

[**NOTE**:[The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli) ]

**mysqli**

(where, `$con` is connection)

```
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, "INSERT INTO driving(user_id,country,l_vehicle,van,truck,tr_trailer) VALUES (?, ?, ?,?, ?, ?)");
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'dsssss',$user->employeeid,$lightv,$van,$truck,$trailer);
```

Read [Prepared Statements](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp)